# Citations and bibliography style for literature

Tags: bibliographies

I've been using tetex in my Slackware box for scientific papers once in a while.  But now, I need some help to aid another person, in setting up her system with TeX Live in Ubuntu, for Literature texts.

The citations should look like:

```
(Leag, 1997: 582) 
(Leag, 1997: 582-585)
```

Note: There's a bib entry for the book of author Leag written in 1997, but not for the passage of the text on page 582. So, what to do in this kind of cases?  Should a bibliographic entry be entered for each page where a note was taken from a book?  Or is it possible to create just one bibliographic entry and be possible to write the number of page when using `\cite{xxx pages}`?

There are also some (special to me) kind of citations, like:

```
(apud Trofon, 1978: 9)
```

when the citation is indirect, an author that cites another one.

Some other citations must appear as:

```
(ibidem)
(Idem, p. 300)
```

And footnotes as:

```
Apud, Seixo et Abreu, 1998: 214
Drivaux, (1984) Poésie Complet, Paris, Éditions du Gramour, p.314
Ibidem
Idem, p. 300
```

For a book or thesis (author, *title of book*, place, editor and year)

```
Martins, António, *Sebastianismo*, Coimbra, Mar da Palavra, 2005.
```

Article collection (author name, "name of article", in *book* (coordinators [note that author is one of the coordinators], pages, place, editor and year.

```
Martins, António, “Realismo”, in *Geografia literária* (coordenação de António Martins e Manuel Ricardo; autor do artigo), pp. 7-18, Coimbra, Barco à vela, 2010.
```

And as: author, *name of book*, (author of edition/notes/preface), number of edition, place, editor, year

```
Pardo Bazán, Emilia, *Los Pazos de Ulloa* (edición de Maria de los Ángeles Ayala), Décima Edición, Madrid, Cátedra Letras Hispánicas, 2009.
```

Is there any bibliographic style that permits doing all this? Or do I have to adapt one? (Although I've never done such job and it doesn't seem easy for me)

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use at present? And, do you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `harvard`?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer, but I suggest to use `biblatex`. Run `texdoc biblatex` from a terminal window to look at the very detailed manual. Also there are plenty questions/answers in  this site. In  particular look at

- [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots)
- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)
- [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles)

For the first part of the question, use  `\cite[582]{leag97key}` and `\cite[582-585]{leag97key}`.